# what is the difference between JavaRDD<Double> and JavaDoubleRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Just noticed that there is a JavaDoubleRDD type, Can someone explain what is the difference between JavaRDD and JavaDoubleRDD? Which way should we use when defining RDD for double type?

Answer (score 0):

Java is just not expressive enough to encode all functionality of `RDD<Double>`. In particular `JavaDoubleRDD` offers a bunch of functions which are meaningful only for numeric containers, including, but not limited to:

- `sum`.
- `stats`.
- `mean`.

and so on.

Obviously these are not applicable for arbitrary `Object`, so generic `JavaRDD` cannot expose these methods.